# Parse stdout and run command if line matches

Tags: unix, command-line-interface, xargs

I would like to parse the stdout of a command and run a command if a line matches. Taking for example the output of `cat cities.txt` is

```
paris
amsterdam
munich
berlin
london
brussels
```

I would like to echo this same list, but run a command for any city which starts with the letter b.

```
cat cities.txt | <command here ... echo $city starts with b>
```

should output something like

```
paris
amsterdam
munich
berlin
berlin starts with b
london
brussels
brussels starts with b
```

Comment: Maybe use [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html) for this? Experiment!

Comment: @shellter Yes, this is a stupid example, but the idea is that I need to execute another command when it DOES match.

Answer (score 2):

A simple `bash` script for this:-

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r line
do
    [[ $line == b* ]] && echo -e "$line\n$line starts with b" || echo "$line"
done <file
```

Running the script produces

```
$ bash script.sh
paris
amsterdam
munich
berlin
berlin starts with b
london
brussels
brussels starts with b
```

Steps:-

1. Reading the file line-by-line
2. If line starts with 'b', append the string as needed, else append it as such
3. To avoid useless use of 'cat' command `<(file)` process-substitution done

`echo` has the `-e` flag to enable interpretation of special-characters `\n` in this case.

You can run some other commands for the matching lines by replacing `echo` after the `&&` part which matches them and for non matching lines after the `||` condition. I have demonstrated the same below with dummy command names `cmd_for_matching_lines` and `cmd_for_non_matching_lines`.

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r line
do
    [[ $line == b* ]] && cmd_for_matching_lines "$line" || cmd_for_non_matching_lines "$line"
done <file
```

Answer (score 2):

The portable solution, without bashisms such as `[[ ]]`, I'd write it as

```
#!/bin/sh
while read city; do
  case $city in
    (b*) echo $city starts with b;;
  esac
done < cities.txt
```

Note how easily this is extended to be case insensitive (use `([Bb]*)` instead) and to augment with tests for other initials.